# Can wheels with XDR and hyperglide drivers be swapped on a bike without readjustment?

Tags: cassette, compatibility

I have two wheels I hope to use on the same bike, which is set up with an 11 speed, Rival 1 groupset.

The wheel currently on the bike has a Hyperglide driver and a SRAM PG-1130 cassette.

The (proposed) 2nd wheel has an XDR driver, and an XG-1150 cassette.

Both are 11 speed, and nearly the same ranges: 10-42 and 11-42. Will I be able to swap wheels without readjusting the derailleur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can get two wheels to be identical, or close enough, to be able to swap wheels without adjusting anything. In theory the hub/cassette spacing should be identical so you shouldn't need to adjust the derailleur.

For shifting the critical spacing will be from the inside face of the frame dropout to the smallest cog.  This spacing can be adjusted by adding thin shims to the freehub body to move the cassette slightly to the right. Both of your wheels will support this.

The procedure to adjust the shifting:
Adjust the derailleur for the first wheel and then replace with the second wheel. If shifting on the 2nd wheel is slow to the smaller cog, then the fix would be to move the cassette farther left but this is impossible. So your 1st wheel needs a cassette shim. This will move the cassette slightly to the right.

If OTOH the 2nd wheel's shifting to the larger cogs is slow, then the 2nd wheel should get a shim to push the cassette slightly right.

Alternatively you may find the two wheels are almost identical and you only need to make a very slight adjustment to the derailleur cable tension when moving from one wheel to another. I have this issue with two sets of 11 speed wheels and an Ultegra setup.  The difference is roughly 1 full turn of my cable adjuster - very minor.

Similarly there are shims available for disk rotors. The spacing between rotor and pad is very small so there is little margin for manufacturing tolerances.

Answer (score 1):

The two cassettes are compatible with the derailleur. [SRAM's compatibility chart for road components](https://www.servicearchive.sram.com/sites/default/files/techdocs/gen0000000005743_rev_b_2018_road_compatibility_map.pdf) says that the Force 1 derailleur is compatible with the 10-42 XG-1150 cassette. The concern would be that that the derailleur doesn't have enough total capacity to handle the the extra tooth difference between the cassette sizes but it does according to SRAM.

You'll possibly have to adjust derailleur indexing when swapping the wheels as the two hubs will not put the cassettes in exactly the same position relative to the frame.

Comment: I was really more concerned about the latter point, adjusting the derailleur. While it's not an especially difficult task it's substantially more time consuming than just swapping out a wheel.

Comment: I would have though that cassette (and disc brake rotor) shims would be available for just this situation. I've never really looked into whether they are.